# linux checking number of files subdirectory - providing wrong variable result when subdirectory searching for does not exist

Tags: linux, bash

I have created a script that goes through specific subdirectories of files and tells me how many files are in each sub-directory that start with s.  My problem occurs when it is searching and the sub-directory has failed to be created.  For some reason, when the sub-directory that this script is searching for does not exist, it replaces the output with another previously created variable????

I am writing this in bash for linux.

I am looking at the following subdirectories...

```
participantdirectory/EmotMRI 
participantdirectory/EmotMRI/firstfour/
participantdirectory/T1
```

So, this is the output I should get, when the subdirectory exists and everything is ok.  It is the same for all files (if it is correct).

```
/home/orkney_01/jsiegel/ruth_data/participants/analysis2/1206681446/20090303/14693
16 in firstfour
776 in EmotMRI folder
2 files in T1 folder
```

For a directory which does not have a subdirectory created, I get this output...

```
bash: cd: /home/orkney_01/jsiegel/ruth_data/participants/analysis2/2102770508/20090210 /14616/EmotMRI/firstfour/: No such file or directory

/home/orkney_01/jsiegel/ruth_data/participants/analysis2/2102770508/20090210/14616
776 in firstfour
114 in EmotMRI folder
2 files in T1 folder
```

I think that, because firstfour is a subdirectory of EmotMRI, when firstfour folder hasn't been created, it substitutes the scan numbers in EmotMRI for this answer?  The number of scans in EmotMRI (in this instance is correct).  Here is my script below.  If this is happening, how do I stop it from doing this?

```
for d in $(cat /home/orkney_01/jsiegel/ruth_data/lists/full_participant_list_location_may20)

do

    if [ -d "$d" ]

            then

                    gr="failed"

                    er="failed"

                    fr="failed"

                    cd $d/EmotMRI/firstfour/

                    gr=$(ls s*| wc -l)

                     echo " "

                    echo "$d"

                    echo "$gr in firstfour"

                    cd $d/EmotMRI/

                    er=$(ls s*| wc -l)

                    echo "$er in EmotMRI folder"

                    cd $d/T1/

                    fr=$(ls s*| wc -l)

                    echo "$fr files in T1 folder"

                    cd $d/EmotMRI

            else

                    echo "$d is currently not available in directory"

    fi

done

cd /home/orkney_01/jsiegel/ruth_data/

echo "Check complete"
```

I know you will probably have many improvements on this script, I am very new to linux.  Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you set gr to the output of `ls s* | wc -l` regardless of whether you successfully change your working directory. When that cd fails, it leaves you in whatever directory you were in previously.

You can combine your cd command into your other commands to set gr:

```
gr=$(cd $d/EmotMRI/firstfour/ && ls s* | wc -l || echo failed)
```

This way, if you successfully cd into the subdirectory, gr will be set to the output of the commands after `&&`. Otherwise, gr will be set to the output of the command after the `||`. You can do the same thing with er and fr.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error messages that you shoud fix.  Cd is failing because you are not allowed to change into a non-existent directory. Your shell will just stay in the directory it was in.  It looks like you know how to test for directory existence, so you should just do that more to avoid trying to go into non-existent directories.